Fastest way to give 3D Buildings/Skyscrapers Parallax Occlusion Mapped Rooms?
What is the fastest ways to scatter the three square Parallax Rooms around the building in the second image, other than doing it by hand.
Initial thoughts were to somehow create a Vertex Group with hand-placed vertices, and then use the particle system to scatter them around the building.
If any of the ideas suggest how I could also randomize their arrangement in the process that'd be even better




To the people that down voted this question could you clarify how the OP can improve his post? You could use geometry nodes to instance on certain faces of the base building. You may need a dual mesh node to find the face centers.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you
